# How to build gradle subprojects with consistent command?

Tags: gradle, grails, build.gradle

I'm trying to create a parameterised jenkins task that can build any of my projects. My projects have some stuff in common, so they are organised under the one hierarchy:

```
---p1
 |-p2
 |-p3
 |-p4
 |-p5--p5a
     |-p5b
```

so I build any of p1-p4 with a command like:

```
gradle :${project}:bootWar
```

and I have in my top level settings.gradle:

```
include 'p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5:p5a', 'p5:p5b'
```

but p5 is different, it has 2 sub projects. I can't build p5 with the above command, because it says:

> Task 'bootWar' not found in project ':p5'.

This seems odd, because I can do:

```
cd p5 ; gradle bootWar
```

and that somehow works, it calls the bootWar task in the 2 subprojects. But it's not really convenient to do that in Jenkins.

How can I configure gradle, so that I can be in the top level folder, and enter

```
gradle :p5:bootWar
```

and have it do the bootWar task in both sub projects?

Comment: If you run `gradlew bootWar` from the root of the multiproject, and don't specify which subprojects, then the `bootWar` task will be run in every subproject that contains that task, and the others will be ignored (won't cause an error).

Comment: Are you saying that `p5` is configured as a subproject in the multiproject build of `p1`, and `p5` is it's own multiproject buld with `p5a` and `p5b` as subprojects of that the `p5` subproject?

Comment: @Jeff I don't want to build all subprojects.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I listed above my settings.gradle at the top level... not sure what else I can say about how it is configured. P1, P2, P3, P4, P5a and P5b have their own build.gradle. There is no other build.gradle. The directory structure is as per above, P5a and P5b are underneath the P5 directory. I could add another build.gradle if it helps to achieve what I'm trying to do. Each of P1, P2, P3, P4 are each a GIT repository. P5a and P5b are in the same respository, because they need to go together.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following build.gradle in the p5 subdirectory works...

```
tasks.register("bootWar") {
  dependsOn(':p5:p5a:bootWar')
  dependsOn(':p5:p5b:bootWar')
}

tasks.register("clean") {
  dependsOn(':p5:p5a:clean')
  dependsOn(':p5:p5b:clean')
}
```

This is not ideal because every conceivable task has to be listed in build.gradle. For some reason with only a single level hierarchy gradle seems able to deal with it automatically.